# Invalid xml characters String catalog Xcode 15

Tags: ios, localization, xcode15

Getting Invalid xml characters error for Vietnamese language when trying to migrate to String Catalog in Xcode 15

> An error occurred when migrating
> Demo/Resources/Localization/Localizable.strings: Invalid xml
> characters: U+8 at index 4 of "Xem lô trinh hoc tâp"

I want to migrate my whole project for Vietnamese language